# Shortening repeated actions with different id`s

Tags: javascript, optimization

I am trying to write a script that does the same thing on button press for multiple id`s. Is there a way to shorten this down in any way?

```
function start(){
    var b1,b2,b3,b4 = true;
    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick=btn1;
    document.getElementById('btn2').onclick=btn2;
    document.getElementById('btn3').onclick=btn3;
    document.getElementById('btn4').onclick=btn4;
}

function btn1(b1) {
    if(b1){
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.opacity=".25";
    b1=false;
    }
}
function btn2(b2) {
    if(b2){
    document.getElementById('btn2').style.opacity=".25";
    b2=false;
    }
}
function btn3(b3) {
    if(b3){
    document.getElementById('btn3').style.opacity=".25";
    b3=false;
    }
}
function btn4(b4) {
    if(b4){
    document.getElementById('btn4').style.opacity=".25";
    b4=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a shorter code with the intent of improving styling or optimization?

Comment: sure.. use a class instead of an id then attach the event to every element with that class

Comment: Just a side note: I am not sure about what you want to achieve with `b1=false` but, if what you want to do is to disable the button when it is clicked, rather than changing its opacity I would suggest adding the `disabled` attribute: `btn.setAttribute('disabled', true)`

Answer (score 1):

Create one function for all of the buttons and add them with a loop. You can target them with a class. Snippet below:

```js
function start(){
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].onclick = buttonFunction;
    }
}
start();

function buttonFunction(e) {
    e.currentTarget.style.opacity=".25";
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="btn1">1</button>
<button class="button" id="btn2">2</button>
<button class="button" id="btn3">3</button>
<button class="button" id="btn4">4</button>
```

Comment: Prefer using `this` or `e.currentTarget` over `e.target` though, in case there is an element nested inside the `<button>`.

Comment: I tried implementing it to my code but it didn't work. Then I tried creating a new document and it still didn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Correct, @Bergi

Comment: @TickyPlays I'm not sure. Are you creating the HTML structure properly? Is your javascript loaded in the HTML file or from an external .js file?

Comment: Yes, I have the right HTML structure, and I am loading the javascript in the HTML file.

Comment: @TickyPlays is the javascript at the end of the document before the closing </body> tag? If you are able, you may message me and I can check out your actual file.